# Evaluating the limit of a sequece

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be an integrable function which is continuous at 1. Let k be a fixed positive integer and let $$a_n=\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{n+k})}dx$$

Find $L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n(L-a_n)$

Any idea would be appreciated. I don't even know how to start this one.

Comment: Did you try the dominated convergence theorem to calculate L?

Comment: I've never heard of that theorem. A quick search on wiki reveals the reason why. I have not yet studied Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: What are the theorems about exchange of limit and integrals you know ?

Comment: I know plenty of real analysis theorems. Do you have anything concrete in mind that would help with this problem?

Comment: If you don't know how to start a problem, you can include the context where you encountered it: what book? What course? What methods have you been looking at recently? This information helps others write more focused answers. Questions without context are often put "on hold" - you can improve the question at any time by editing it.

Comment: My math professor gave me this as preparation for a math competition I will be attending next month. I am a first year undergrad studying computer science. He used Crux Mathematicorum as a source for this I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you can cut the integral in two :

We cut then the integral at $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ :

$$a_n = \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx + \int_{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}^1 \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx $$

Then the first part is :

$$\int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} \frac{f(x)}{(1+{(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}^n)(1+{(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}^{k+n})}dx \leq \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx \leq  \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} \frac{f(x)}{(1)(1)}dx $$

i.e.

$$\frac{1}{(1+{(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}^n)(1+{(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}^{k+n})} \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} f(x) dx \leq \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx \leq  \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}} f(x)dx $$

And this converge to $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx$

The second part, as f is continous at 1, for n big enough, there exist M>0 that verify :

$$\forall x \in [1-\frac{1}{2^n},1], f(1)-M < f(x) < f(1)+M$$

so in  $[1-\frac{1}{2^n},1]$,

$$\frac{f(1)-M}{(1+(1-\frac{1}{n})^n)(1+(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k+n})}< \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})} < f(1)+M$$

Hence

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{f(1)-M}{(1+(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^n)(1+(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{k+n})}< \int_{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}^1 \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx < \frac{1}{2^n}(f(1)+M)$$

And both side converge to 0

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to cut the integral elsewhere. At $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ for exemple, will modify the proof

Comment: @RRL makes a valid point. I believe the limit might depend on k. A very good idea though.

Comment: No the limit is indeed $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ by monotone convergence. @Tryss should be able to fix it.

Comment: I modified the proof. @RRL : it's way easier when you can use the powerfull theorems ^^

Comment: Nice approach (+1)

Comment: I need a clarification for the last bit of the proof. How did you arrive from this bit $\frac{f(1)-M}{(1+(1-\frac{1}{n})^n)(1+(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k+n})}< \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})} < f(1)+M$ to $\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{f(1)-M}{(1+(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^n)(1+(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{k+n})}< \int_{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}^1 \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx < \frac{1}{2^n}(f(1)+M)$ Never mind I got it :)

Comment: I just integrated between $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ and 1. Because if you have $f(x) < g(x)$ for all x, then $\int_a^b f(x) dx < \int_a^b g(x) dx$

Comment: Nice approach indeed

Comment: I think you can use the same method for the second part.

Comment: I just tried on paper the second part by splitting at $ \frac{n}{2^n}$ . The second part I believe works out but I am having troubles with the integral $ \int_0^{1-\frac{n}{2^n}} f(x)- \frac{f(x)}{(1+x^n)(1+x^{k+n})}dx$